# How to update the value from one dictionary to another

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I have two dictionaries 1.Primary, 2. Secondary

- Need to check first `field` of both dictionary
- If field is same compare the title with primary and secondary

*If field and title is same then From Primary dictionary add `count` to secondary dictionary

Primary dictionary

```
{"Latest":[
  {
    "name": "Employee",
    "field": "employee",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "A",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "count": "1"
      },
      {
        "title": "C",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "count": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Project",
    "field": "project",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "NEW_York",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "count": "3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Designation",
    "field": "designation",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "Developer",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "count": "1"
      }
    ]
}
]}
```

Secondary dictionary

```
[
  {
    "name": "Employee",
    "field": "employee",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "A",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "count": "null"
      },
      {
        "title": "B",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "count": "null"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Project",
    "field": "project",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "NEW_York",
        "paragraph": "test",
        "count": "null"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Designation",
    "field": "designation",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "Tester",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "count": "null"
      }
    ]
}
]
```

Expected out

```
{"Latest":[
  {
    "name": "Employee",
    "field": "employee",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "A",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "count": "1"
      },
      {
        "title": "C",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "count": "1"
      },
      {
        "title": "B",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "count": "null"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Project",
    "field": "project",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "NEW_York",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "count": "3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Designation",
    "field": "designation",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "Developer",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "count": "1"
      },
      {
        "title": "Tester",
        "paragraph": "null"
        "count": "null"
      }
    ]
}
]}
```

COde

```
for primary_elem in primary['Latest']:
    primary_titles = [value['title'] for value in primary_elem['values']]
    for secondary_elem in secondary:
        if secondary_elem['field'] == primary_elem['field']:
            for secondary_value in secondary_elem['values']:
                if secondary_value['title']  in primary_titles:
                    for value in primary_elem['values']:
                       if secondary_value['title'] ==  value['title']:
                          secondary_value['count'] = value['count']
```

got error string element must be integers

How to reduce one loop also 6 to 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
for primary_elem in primary['Latest']:
    primary_titles = [value['title'] for value in primary_elem['values']]
    for secondary_elem in secondary:
        if secondary_elem['field'] == primary_elem['field']:
            for secondary_value in secondary_elem['values']:
                if secondary_value['title']  in primary_titles:
                    secondary_elem['count'] = primary_elem['count']
```

To

```
for buttfart_junior in primary['Latest']:
    buttfart_senior = [value['title'] for value in buttfart_junior['values']]
    for young_buttfart in secondary:
        if young_buttfart['field'] == buttfart_senior['field']:
            for buttfart_farts in buttfart_junior['values']:
                if buttfart_farts['title']  in buttfart_senior:
                    buttfart_junior['count'] = buttfart_senior['count']
```

Comment: have you tested ? TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str